# NiFI toDate function in UpdateRecord alert the year and month

Tags: java, apache-nifi

My input flow file (CSV) contains the date as `20220103`.
I want to create 3 properties as date, year, and month from the above input.

So I use the UpdateRecord processor with the below configurations:

[image: processor configurations]

```
/date  format(toDate(/date, "yyyyMMdd"),"yyyy-MM-dd")
/day   format(toDate(/date, "yyyyMMdd"),"dd")
/month format(toDate(/date, "yyyyMMdd"),"MM")
/year  format(toDate(/date, "yyyyMMdd"),"yyyy")
```

It returns output flow file as below:

```json
[
  {
    "date": "2022-01-03",
    "year": 2021,
    "month": 12,
    "day": 3
  }
]
```

It correctly converts the `/date` attribute, but `/year` and `/month` is different from input. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot depend on a field/attribute that is modified itself. Try this:

```
/dateFormatted  format(toDate(/date, "yyyyMMdd"),"yyyy-MM-dd")
/day   format(toDate(/date, "yyyyMMdd"),"dd")
/month format(toDate(/date, "yyyyMMdd"),"MM")
/year  format(toDate(/date, "yyyyMMdd"),"yyyy")
```

Output:

```json
{
  "date" : "20220103",
  "day" : "03",
  "dateFormatted" : "2022-01-03",
  "year" : "2022",
  "month" : "01"
}
```

Comment: same result brother

Comment: I replaced dd with DD and MM with mm and now it works.